# What does " supergroup " means?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

I was reading a Hypergraph Isomorphism than I encounter a new term called  " supergroup ", I know what a subgroup means but about supergroup I don't know anything. I tried to read from the wikipedia and get this :

> The concept of supergroup is a generalization of that of group. In other words, every supergroup carries a natural group structure, but there may be more than one way to structure a given group as a supergroup.

Even after reading his I am feeling like I am not getting the feeling that I have understood the definition of supergroup.

Please explain the defintion of supergroup with example and what is its significance in group theory.

Thanks in advance.

**Reference** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup_(physics) (Please note that in this article they have defined the term  " Lie supergroup " but I am asking about " supergroup ". I don't know these two terms are same or different)

Comment: Why don't you quote the **definition** of a supergroup? The passage you quoted is not a definition. Better yet, why don't you tell us what book or web page you quoted that passage from? You hinted that it's from a Wikipedia article. Which Wikipedia article is that?

Comment: @ bof I have linked the wikipedia page.

Comment: As you note, the Wiki page defines only *Lie supergroup* ... a group object in the category of supermanifolds.  It does not state the definition, or even say there is such a thing, as *supergroup* alone.

Comment: As [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup) says, it is "a rarely used term in mathematics for the counterpart of a subgroup." That is, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $G$ is a supergroup of $H$. This has nothing to do with the notion from super Lie theory.